# How to read a RSA public key to import it

Tags: python, encryption, rsa

i am trying to do the following:

```
  PK_ID = RSA.importKey(PK_ID)
```

to use the PK_ID at a later stage to do some hybrid encryption

however i get the error:

```
    PK_ID = RSA.importKey(PK_ID)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Crypto/PublicKey/RSA.py", line 682, in importKey
    raise ValueError("RSA key format is not supported")
ValueError: RSA key format is not supported
```

They PK_ID is of len 20 and type str

To get this value i retrieve a document containing the encdoded key :

```
service-key
-----BEGIN RSA PUBLIC KEY-----
MIGJAoGBALzyd52zz2UBbHxE7LbtVVtdLN/BcV0io7kQN2K7BXChExSlFd/KXuO1
FZ1Qc435BNgUXLhSPy7bEgmANY6ysK1FNVqt/X1rG9ZdPGRAxuD/Mv/HRnnBHHzn
IgRpDgcpq01vE50ezRrIGKrqRcyH4q/hLjSFhl1AdwMVraPk+By/AgMBAAE=
-----END RSA PUBLIC KEY-----
```

i then extract the data between the --- and then decode this by using the decode base 64 command :

```
service_key_decrypted.append(base64.b64decode(i))
```

and then hash this value :

```
#Hashes an input with SHA1
def hash_item(i):
    hash_value = SHA.new()
    hash_value.update(i)
    hash_value = hash_value.digest()
    return hash_value
```

how can i import this key by using the RSA.importKey command ?

i have also tried this wthout hashing it and still get the same error

Comment: Have you tried pouring gasoline over the key and setting on fire prior to importing it? Maybe that will work. Seriously, [this](https://www.dlitz.net/software/pycrypto/api/current/Crypto.PublicKey.RSA-module.html#importKey) documentation suggests that base64-decoding  that data should work. Your RSA key is in the PKCS#1 RsaPublicKey ASN.1 format. In your code snippet you seem to be appending it to something. Don't do that.

Comment: What do you mean with "and then hash this value"? Why? What do you do with the hash value?